# buzzer doesn't work at testing with DC power

Tags: piezo-buzzer

i have a motherboard buzzer HYCOM mod:HY-05 i am trying to make it sound by providing 
3 to 8 vdc as it  says in the data-sheet but still no voice coming 
and i have also a buzzer KC-1206: still got the same problem ,is it possible that the two of
them are damaged ?
if someone knows how to operate ( :

datasheet

[HYCOM mod:HY-05](http://www.hycomdevice.com.tw/comm/upfile/d_030728_06135.pdf)

[KC-1206](http://elcodis.com/parts/6007289/KC-1206.html#datasheet)

Comment: PC Buzzers typically require a square wave (on/off pattern) to make a sound. Off = GND, On = 3-8V.

Answer (score 2):

They may get damaged if you continue to power them with DC. Buzzers work in similar fashion with speakers but they can't reproduce a wide spectrum of audio frequencies.

Being used in the PC increases the possibility that the buzzer was fed with a square wave audio signal of a few (1 - 2 ) kHz.

I suggest you build a 555 square wave generator for your buzzers. Something similar to this,  that should drive a transistor with the buzzer as load.

[image]

Circuit source: http://ehelion.net/projects/digitalclock/555timer.html